# SQL Server Query returning all rows in a table instead of MAX()

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, max

Im trying to return the highest/last hour meter reading for each piece of equipment in an inventory, however, the query below lists all of the instances even using MAX.

```
select      sil.[Posting Date], 
            mre.[Service Item No_], 
            sil.[Job Code], 
            max(mre.[Reading]) as 'Hour Reading'     

from        [$meter reading entry]mre left outer join
            [$service invoice line]sil on mre.[Service Item No_] = sil.[Service Item No_]

where       sil.[Job Code] = 200


group by    mre.[Service Item No_], sil.[Job Code], mre.[Reading], sil.[Posting Date]
```

Comment: Your sil join isn't really doing anything. What happens when you take out the join and just use the main table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because mre.[Reading] is used in GROUP BY clause also. To get the desired result remove the mre.[Reading] from the GROUP BY and try again.

```
select      sil.[Posting Date], 
            mre.[Service Item No_], 
            sil.[Job Code], 
            max(mre.[Reading]) as 'Hour Reading'     

from        [$meter reading entry]mre left outer join
            [$service invoice line]sil on mre.[Service Item No_] = sil.[Service Item No_]

where       sil.[Job Code] = 200


group by    mre.[Service Item No_], sil.[Job Code], sil.[Posting Date]
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you so much.